# Почему Qt Creator не правильно компилирует программы

Tags: c++, qt

Часто возникает проблема, что Qt либо компилирует не верно, либо вовсе не компилирует правильную программу. Иногда спасает кнопка "Сборка во всех конфигурациях", но не всегда. Стопроцентный вариант это пересоздание проекта, но можно ли как то без этого? Как это обходить, потому что очень много сил уходит на дебаг, когда ошибки и нет вовсе. Тут например у меня каким-то чудесным образом вместо int* keys в дебаге получается int keys. И что самое интересное: при обращений к keys[<0, 1 и тд>], ошибок во время выполнения не возникает, записывается только по индекса 0 и дальше keys равно просто целому числу. Такая же проблема и с массивом указателей собственного типа SmartPtr.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: весьма странный код. Память, которая выделенная под это все помечена как baadf00d (даже для keys!), есть подозрение, что отлаживается другой код. Плюс нужно понимать, что QtCreator не умеет компилировать код - это не компилятор. Компилирует какой то реальный компилятор (студийный или gcc/clang/mingw).

Comment: Это постоянная проблема в Qt, что отлаживается другой код, даже не старая версия. Он ведет себя не предсказуемо. Была ситуация, что в цикле for есть условие выхода, но компилятор плевал на это и шел по циклу дальше, пока не залазил не в свою память и программа вылетала. Вот и спрашиваю, может кто-то знает как решить эту проблему в Qt с такими ситуациями.

Comment: а может просто в коде было маленькое UB? в данном случае, возможно у Вас был `for (unsigned int a = 10; a >= 0; a--) {...}` ?

Comment: В коде ошибок нет, если пересоздать проект и просто копировать туда код, оно начинает адекватно работать и дебагер тоже корректно все показывает